# Infinite Scroll Reactjs with Youtube Api Search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, youtube

I am trying to implement a infinite scroll in my youtube api and i have a great problem about how to do this

I am trying to implement a infinite scroll in my youtube api and i have a great problem about how to do this
my code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that [AFAIK](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/4) you can't retrieve more than 500 YouTube results.

Answer (score 0):

Hey [@Dimitris Kermizidis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14220202/dimitris-kermizidis),

#### Add some more details for better understanding.

If you're facing problem to impalement infinite scroll in ReactJS. Then, There is an easy way to use packages.
I think that package, and its documentation is very easy you could try this.

> npm i react-infinite-scroll-component

Here is the link:-

[**react-infinite-scroll-component**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component)

If you don't want to use packages, then there are a lot of article about that to how to do that:-

[**implement an infinite scroll**](https://medium.com/suyeonme/react-how-to-implement-an-infinite-scroll-749003e9896a)